# A better way to update state in redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Please advise me what is better way. Both ways return same result.

```
payload = { value1: 'test1', value2: 'test2' }
```

Example1:

```
case EXAMPLE_TYPE:
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.payload
  };
```

Example2:

```
case EXAMPLE_TYPE:
  return {
    ...state,
    value1: action.payload.value1,
    value2: action.payload.value2
  };
```

Comment: Spreading `...action.payload` is totally fine. What's best depends on your use-case and your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

*Your both examples are ok.*

Depending on what you need, you can use them both.

Personally I prefer to destructure the payload first, and then insert them into the new state object like so.

```
const { value1, value2 } = action.payload
return {
   ...state,
   value1,
   value2,
}
```